# org-mode and insert-sliced-image

Tags: org-mode, images, scrolling

I read in the [Emacs manual online](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Showing-Images.html) about using `insert-sliced-image` to create smooth scrolling with inline images.

I would like to use this to override `org-toggle-inline-images`, so that I can get smooth scrolling with images in `org-mode`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am facing the same issue.  Looking at the org-mode source code it looks like there are some functions there for displaying images in the org.el file.  At this point I understand too little about what is going on there and have too little time to dive into it myself.

Comment: See my answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78047832/org-mode-inline-images-display-with-insert-sliced-image/78064990#78064990.